# How to stop/cancel a task in ScheduledExecutorService at particular time?

Tags: java, concurrency, scheduled-tasks

For example, I have a task which should be executed between 8:00-20:00 every minites every day.

so i calculate the time gap between 8:00 and the time which my app started for `initialDelay`, and use `Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor().scheduleAtFixedRate(command, initialDelay, 1, TimeUnit.MINUTE)`.

The question is, do I need the second timer to observe the task and cancel it when the clock comes to 20:00? or do I have to compare if the time is 20:00 at every time when the task's executed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably need a real scheduler.

See Quartz https://quartz-scheduler.org

It should fit your needs

For the cron syntax : http://quartz-scheduler.org/api/2.2.0/org/quartz/CronTrigger.html

Or with a fluent API http://quartz-scheduler.org/api/2.2.0/org/quartz/TriggerBuilder.html

Comment: Thanks, that's really helpful.